# Intellij idea. Can't publish apk to Google play

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, google-play, google-play-services

I can't publish my apk to google play service and I can't understand why. 
I'm new to android development so appreciate any feedback
Some screenshots are below.

Here is how my project looks in idea:

[image]

Here is app manifest: 
[image]

1) I create a certificate and signed apk.
[image: signed apk]

2) I tried to upload it wich resulted in error
[image]

I beg you for help, because I have already killed some days searching a solution.

Comment: Have you tried changing your package name to something other than com.android like the error message says?

Comment: Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I'm sure you are right. Thank you. Can you post it? I will mark as an answer. I've edited the post(added manifest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error is clear: you cannot use `com.android` as package name so you must change it. Since you're not using graddle, I think you're forced to do 2 things

- Rename your package as @Eduardo Dennis or applying any other strategy
- Rename your `package` attribute on manifest.xml to new package name

Then you can rebuild your apk binary and publish again. Take your time to pick the correct package name since this can't be changed once you published your first version.

Answer (score 2):

You need to rename your package. Instead of com.android name it something unique, because that is how the play store identifies your app.

An easy way of doing this is right clicking inside your application and add new package. Then just transfer over the classes, and you should be able to publish your app.